# Создание PPPoE соединения

Tags: windows, java, pppoe

Необходимо создать программу, которая будет создавать/проверять PPPoE соединение, просматривать состояние, синхронизироваться с веб сайтом. Предполагаемый язык написания Java. Буду очень признателен, если кто-нибудь сможет подсказать, какие библиотеки использовать (желательно бесплатные и работающие на системах Windows 98 и выше) или как с этим работать вообще.

Comment: Про язык написание я сказал, что предположительно, т.е. если нет возможности написания на нем, то можно и что-то другое. К сожалению пока что я даже не знаю с чего начать.

Answer (score 2):

Java не поддерживает протоколы такого низкого уровня (Самый низкий TCP/UDP). Как вариант, писать PPPoE-клиента на C. Потом объединять с джавой посредством JNI, но это если нужна интеграция с Java.